# Why my Arrayformula doesn't work

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-arrays

I have this google sheet :

[image]

link is here :

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_-AcgJud2DclKtarcJj39DNB84CzthUzO_n5F8mBgKY/edit?usp=sharing

On the top is my matrix table. It has key on the left and data on the right. I want to pull the key based on the data if the data is not null.

On the 2nd table i used manual copy/paste and it works perfectly. The formula in B10 :

```
=ifna( vlookup(B2,{B$2:B$6,$A$2:$A$6},2,0) ,)
```

But on the 3rd table i tried arrayformula , and the output is wrong. Can someone spot what is the problem with the formula in B17 :

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ifna( vlookup(B2:M6,{B$2:B$6,$A$2:$A$6},2,0) ,) )
```

Comment: Your bottom formula is telling sheets to try to find every cell value in the range `B2:M6` within ONLY the single-column range `B2:B6`. It seems you need to spend some further time studying the basics of how VLOOKUP works.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't understand your underlying logic in choosing `VLOOKUP` for this task; and then, as I noted in the comment, it doesn't seem you yet understand the basics of how `VLOOKUP` even works.

That said, you don't need `VLOOKUP` at all. Try this simple formula:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:M6="",,A2:A6))`